# Pyorient : Querying a vertex in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

this works

```
data = client.query("SELECT FROM Person WHERE id = '1000'")
print(data)
```

but this doesn't

```
results = graph.query(Person, name='Prakash')
print(results)
```

this throws an error saying

```
TypeError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a graph db  called "pydb", empty, (i use graphic interface with orientdb 2.2.28 in Windows 10) and then, using this code (runned in eclipse), you have the list of animal vertexs:

[image]

The result:

[image]

The guide is here: https://github.com/orientechnologies/pyorient

Comment: and again  :'( No raw query plz.